# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been having lots of imports issues when it comes to TensorFlow and Keras and now I stumbled upon this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17880/703187089.py in <module>
     75 #model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001),metrics=["accuracy"])
     76 
---> 77 model.compile(optimizers.rmsprop_v2(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
     78 
     79 STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

These are the imports:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import regularizers, optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop_v2, adadelta_v2
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question.

Comment: Traceback has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kerns.optimizers.rmsprop_v2` and `kerns.optimizers.adadelta_v2`  are the modules. You want:

```
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adadelta
```

And:

[`optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/RMSprop) (or just `RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)`) instead of `optimizers.rmsprop_v2(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)`

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks so much!